# function not returning value to client from server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs, yo

I have a function to access mongodb using mongoose, the database call works and appears in the console but it doesn't return that array as it should.  Can't figure out why.

```
exports.getPrices = function() {
    return Price.find().exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) { 
            return err;
        }
        console.log(docs);
        return docs;
    });
};
```

the call from the service

```
angular.module('core')
    .factory('Machineprice', [ '$http',
        function($http) {
            return {
                getPrices:function(){  
                    return $http.get('/getPrices')    
                }
            };
        }
    ]
);
```

the controller

```
angular.module('core').controller('MachinePricingController', ['$scope','Machineprice',
    function($scope, Machineprice) {    
        $scope.prices = Machineprice.getPrices();
        console.log($scope.prices);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the `getPrices()` runs asynchronously which means it doesn't return the result instantly. That function returns a **promise** which means the result has to be dealt with in a callback function.

Quote from [AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a
>   configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and
>   **returns a promise**.

To make it work, you have to change the code of your controller.

```
angular.module('core').controller('MachinePricingController', ['$scope', 'Machineprice',

function ($scope, Machineprice) {
    Machineprice.getPrices().then(function (response) {
        $scope.prices = response.data;
        console.log($scope.prices);
    });

}]);
```